# method VS () => method() - Angular 2 done() callback function subscribe Observable RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have a question about done function in subscribe() method when using RxJS.

My application has a code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._dictionaryService.loadDictionary()
  .subscribe(
    dictionary => this.dictionary = dictionary,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    this.loadQuestion);
}
```

and it doesn't work.
But if a change

```
this.loadQuestion);
```

to

```
() => this.loadQuestion());
```

it works ok.

so, this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._dictionaryService.loadDictionary()
  .subscribe(
    dictionary => this.dictionary = dictionary,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    () => this.loadQuestion());
}
```

works well.

`this._dictionaryService.loadDictionary()` gets JSON data from file.

`this.dictionary` is a class property.
When I try to assess this property in 1st example, i get an undefined.
But in 2ns example everything is ok.

So, it works, but I don't understand the difference. I don't understand why 1s example doesn't work.

Could somebody explain me this, please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you write `this.loadQuestion` you're passing a reference to the function `loadQuestion` but you'll be losing the `this` context. When you use the arrow function, the `this` context will be kept.

You could also write `this.loadQuestion.bind(this)` to obtain a `loadQuestion` function with the this context fixed to the current one.